# small problem with this node.js and ejs problem

Tags: ejs

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs:8
    6| </head>
    7| <body>
 >> 8|     <% if(kindofday === saturday) { %>
    9| <h1 style="color: blue"><%= kindofday %> todolist</h1>
   10| 
   11|   <% } else { %>

saturday is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:10:25)
    at list (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\app.js:36:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ANURAG YADAV\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Please include more info in your question. Also the error message is pretty clear: `saturday is not defined`. You either didn't pass `saturday` to EJS, or the variable just was never defined anywhere.

Comment: If you're trying to check if `kindofday` is the string "saturday", that conditional should be `kindofday === "saturday"`